# How to get Zend_Log_Writer to write in a new row?

Tags: php, zend-framework, logging

I have the following code:

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream($path."/../../../../data/logs/Log.log");
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer); 
$logger->info(print_r($xm1,true));
```

The problem is, that every time it writes a log entry, it doesn't append it to a new row.

Ive tried

```
$logger->info("\n\r".print_r($xm1,true));
```

But this has the side effect of putting the date on one line, and starting the information on a new line.

So the question: **How to do get the logger to write every entry on a new row?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you open it with notepad on windows?
Maybe you should try opening it with notepad++?

Comment: sanders is right. Everything in ZF uses linux linebreaks (\n). If you are on windows you need to display such files using programmer's editor (like PSPad, Notepad++ or cygwin editors)

Comment: I will also point out that wordpad usually handles unix linebreaks properly too and is already installed on your computer.